# How to get XMLLINT to put --xpath results as an array

Tags: xml, bash, xmllint

I would like the output of the XMLLINT to get put into an BASH array.  But all I can get is a single string.  The results will return many hits, none with any pattern that can help parse the returned string.

- I have tried --format and redirect ">" to a text file.
- I have tried xpath all instances `//` and just one `/`

#### mcv.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <instance>
        <absolutePath>/abc/def</absolutePath>
    </instance>
    <instance>
        <absolutePath>/abc/hij</absolutePath>
    </instance>
</root>
```

#### mcv.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

declare -a wwArray=()

wwCount=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//absolutePath)' "mcv.xml")

printf "wwCount: '%s' \n" ${wwCount}

i=1

while [ $i -le ${wwCount} ];
do
        wwExtracted=$(xmllint --xpath '//absolutePath['${i}']/text    ()' "mcv.xml")
        printf " - absolutePath: '%s' \n" ${wwExtracted}
        printf " - index: '%d' \n" ${i}
        let i=i+1
done
```

---

Running this, the output is:

```
wwCount: '2'
 - absolutePath: '/abc/def/abc/hij'
 - index: '1'
XPath set is empty
 - absolutePath: ''
 - index: '2'
```

...whereas I would expect it to instead be:

```
wwCount: '2'
 - absolutePath: '/abc/def'
 - index: '1'
 - absolutePath: '/abc/hij'
 - index: '2'
```

Comment: Without having an example input document, we can't actually test this ourselves. That said, note that `ww=$(...)` is a *string* assignment, not an array assignment, and that `for i in $ww` is word-splitting and glob-expanding a string, not iterating over array elements. (Even if `ww` is an array, that operation ignores all but the first element, and operates on that first element as a string).

Comment: ...if `ww` truly were an array, iterating over it would be `for i in "${ww[@]}"`, but to make that true you'd need to assign to it in a completely different way.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `for` to run a `printf` string once per array element -- `printf '%s\n' "${ww[@]}"` would do the trick (if, again, you had actually assigned to an array in the first place).

Comment: Replaced code with a MCV BASH and XML file as per Charles Duffy

Comment: Much better. I also added in actual and (what I presume to be) desired output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *smallest* change needed to make your existing code work is to add parens before the `[$i]`, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
wwCount=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//absolutePath)' "mcv.xml")
for ((i=1; i<=wwCount; i++)); do
        wwExtracted=$(xmllint --xpath '(//absolutePath)['"$i"']/text()' "mcv.xml")
        printf " - absolutePath: '%s' \n" "$wwExtracted"
        printf " - index: '%d' \n" "$i"
done
```

That said, this is really inefficient (running your XPath over and over). Consider switching away from `xmllint` to use XMLStarlet instead, which can be instructed to insert newlines between output elements, so you can tell bash to load those items directly into a real shell array:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
readarray -t items < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//absolutePath' -v './text()' -n <mcv.xml)
printf ' - absolutePath: %s\n' "${items[@]}"
```

Once you've got contents into an array (as created by `readarray` above), you can also iterate by index:

```
for idx in "${!items[@]}"; do
  printf ' - absolutePath: %s\n' "${items[$idx]}"
  printf ' - index: %s\n' "$idx"
done
```

Comment: Thanks so much Charles.

Comment: BTW, if you *want* to use XMLStarlet, but don't have it installed everywhere you need, it's possible to have `xmlstarlet sel` generate an XSLT template you can run anywhere `xsltproc` is installed (which should be available *more* places than `xmllint --xpath`). `xmlstarlet sel -C -t -m '//absolutePath' -v './text()' -n` will generate an XSLT file that can be used in that way.

Comment: excellent construction. I used (and referenced) it for [an answer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/371968/83) in SOes.